# Return arrow and text using ax.annotate in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the object-oriented approach to matplotlib, is there a way to get access to the arrow that is drawn when using ax.annotate.

It seems this command returns the text as an object, but not the arrow. I also can't find the arrow when using the show_children command.

Can this arrow be accessed please? I simply want to get all arrows on my plot and change their color.

```
plt.plot(np.arange(5), 2* np.arange(5))
plt.plot(np.arange(5), 3*np.arange(5))
ax = plt.gca()

text = ax.annotate('TEST', xytext=(2,10), xy=(2,2), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

ax.get_children()
```

returns

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x207dcdba978>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x207de1e47f0>,
 Text(2,10,'TEST'),
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x207dcb81518>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x207de05b320>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x207de0b7828>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x207de1d9080>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x207de1d9f28>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x207de049358>,
 Text(0.5,1,''),
 Text(0,1,''),
 Text(1,1,''),
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x207de049d30>]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the color of an arrow can be set at creation of the annotation using the `color` argument in the `arrowprops`:

```
ax.annotate('TEST', xytext=(.2,.1), xy=(.2,.2), 
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="blue"))
```

If there is really the need to change the color afterwards, you need to obtain the patch of the arrow from the text.
In case an arrow is produced with an `Annotation`, the `Annotation` object has an attribute `arrow_patch`. You can use it to access the arrow patch, as

```
text = ax.annotate( ... )
text.arrow_patch.set_color("red")
```

Of course you could then loop over all children and check if they contain an arrow. Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.gca()

text = ax.annotate('TEST', xytext=(.2,.1), xy=(.2,.2), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
text2 = ax.annotate('TEST2', xytext=(.5,.5), xy=(.2,.2), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

# access each object individually
#text.arrow_patch.set_color("red")
# or

for child in ax.get_children():
    if isinstance(child,type(text)):
        if hasattr(child, "arrow_patch"):
            child.arrow_patch.set_color("red")

plt.show()
```